# How can I rename all files setting 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc?

Tags: linux, bash

It's been a long time that I don't do any shell scripting.

I'm using Bash on a Ubuntu

I've a folder with many jpg pictures with some random name generated by the camera. I want to rename all pictures to create something like 1.jpg, 2.jpg, those sorted by date.

So far, I've ordered the pictures like this 
`ls -alt`
which outputs this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pc-vell pc-vell 3919618 2013-04-29 13:28 P4295809.JPG
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pc-vell pc-vell 4293911 2013-04-29 14:15 P4295810.JPG
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pc-vell pc-vell 3819811 2013-04-29 14:27 P4295811.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc-vell pc-vell 4993078 2013-04-29 23:13 DSCF0880.JPG
```

So I must get `P4295809.JPG` and rename it to `1.JPG`, and so on with the next ones.

I've cut the output to this:

```
DSCF1045.JPG
DSCF1046.JPG
DSCF1048.JPG
DSCF1050.JPG
DSCF1053.JPG
DSCF1054.JPG
DSCF1055.JPG
```

Using `ls -altr | cut -c 55-100`

But now I'm stuck. I don't know how to program a script from that...

Can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `cut` to get only the name, just don't use `l`: `ls -atr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to parse the `ls` output, just loop along what is found in the `/your/dir/*.JPG` expression.

This can work:

```
i=1
for f in /your/dir/*.JPG
do
  mv "$f" "${i}.jpg"
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

It will loop over the files matching `*.JPG` in `/your/dir` and rename them to *counter*.jpg.

Comment: well I had to parse the LS output, because I wanted it sorted by the modification date. But this worked like charm. Thanks!!

Comment: Uhms, I see. In that case you could have used `ls -1t` (note 1 -one- not l -L-), that orders by time and just prints the names.

Comment: Parsing ls is **evil**. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I know, I know (and also a little tired of everybody saying it :D). That's why I did not include it in my answer.

Comment: We all know that parsing ls is evil for many reasons, but this script had to be ran just once, to rename bunch of files, which actually did the trick. I didn't want to have a professional and flawless script for ages, just a workaround. A programmer mind should understand that some answers, even if are not the best, are the most correct for that exact moment.